# Visual Studio 2017 Remote Debugging of Azure App Service Not Working

Tags: visual-studio-2017, remote-debugging, azure-web-app-service

I created a clean Web API .NET Core project and published it, using the default settings, to an Azure App Service, also created using all the defaults.  Then I started up Visual Studio 2017 in Administrator mode and tried to attach the debugger.  I got:

> Unable to find a process called dotnet with arguments
>   .\MyCompany.WebApi.dll. The process may still be
>   starting, please try again.

What is wrong?  Has anyone successfully debugged a App Service with .Net Core remotely.  Seems like kind of a limitation of the environment if not.

**EDIT:** I upgraded to Visual Studio 2019 and was able to remotely debug processes running in Azure.  There seems to be a critical failure with 2017 and Microsoft can't support it.

Comment: 1) Kindly ensure that Remote Debugging is enabled from the Azure Portal and correct VS version is selected from there. 

2) Also, ensure that latest SDK is installed - https://azure.microsoft.com/downloads/



3) You may try the steps outlined in this document which provides a detailed steps on how to enable Remote Debugging for Net core on App Service:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-azure?view=vs-2017#remote_debug_azure_app_service

Comment: Same issue - fully up to date